# Pad data frame per key and accumulation metric Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

before_padding = pd.DataFrame(data={'user_id': [1,1,1,1,2, 2,3],
                                'days_past': [1,2,3,4, 2, 3,2],
                                'pay': [11,12,13,16, 17,18,10]})
```

It shoes per user its ID, how Many days he is in the system, and how much he paid (Accumulated). However for my use i would like to pad it per each user, so that the data will include per each user the maximum and min of days possible (Min and max of all DF) and if there is day without payment record, it will have the value of payment the day before (if exist) or 0 as following:

```
after_padding=pd.DataFrame(data={'user_id': [1,1,1,1,2, 2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
                                'days_past': [1,2,3,4,1 ,2, 3,4,1,2,3,4],
                                'pay': [11,12,13, 16,0,17,18,18,0,10,10,10]})
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape, forward fill missing values, [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) back, replace missing values in start of groups by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = (before_padding.set_index(['user_id','days_past'])['pay']
                    .unstack()
                    .ffill(axis=1)
                    .stack(dropna=False)
                    .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
                    .reset_index(name='pay'))
print (df)
    user_id  days_past  pay
0         1          1   11
1         1          2   12
2         1          3   13
3         1          4   16
4         2          1    0
5         2          2   17
6         2          3   18
7         2          4   18
8         3          1    0
9         3          2   10
10        3          3   10
11        3          4   10
```